# How to change apache Nutch timestamp value

Tags: solr, timestamp, nutch

I am using apache nutch 2.3. Documents are indexed by nutch to solr are ok. But I have to know when a document was indexed in solr. I need time and date. I am getting following format in timestamp for a documents

```
"tstamp": "2015-04-06T10:11:16.619Z"
```

If I suppose that first part is the date then this is third month and not fourth. How I can change this issue.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug. The next fetch time was being mistakenly assigned as the current fetch time.

There is a patch for it:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2045